# When will the Ubuntu 14.04 wallpaper contest start? Or has it already started?

Tags: desktop-background

I saw once some talk about the wallpaper contest on "omgubuntu" but I couldn't manage to find out when it would start. Other than omgubuntu, where can I keep track of the contest?

Oh and how do I participate? ...where can I find such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on IRC, there's channel for the same `#1404wallpaper` in which you can participate and know more. As per [this post](http://hungfu.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/ubuntu-14-04-wallpaper-proposed-approach/), contest kicks off from 10th February 2014 (so keep an eye on the blog as well as on IRC).

Following the tradition of past Ubuntu release, Wallpapers are to be submitted on announced Flickr community, should be conforming [Submission Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Trusty/CommunityWallpapers).

So following on IRC should be good to go. :)

Comment: well thanks alot so far :D I've been trying to communicate through IRC but couldn't manage to. that's what I've reached http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=cplug . and I'm trying to find the contest on flickr, would you help me with that? @Kush

Comment: okay got it! here it is http://www.flickr.com/groups/2484760@N20/ thanks alot :D

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 Wallpaper Contest has already started, and the deadline for all entries is February 27.

Entry is open to everyone, but you’ll need to be a keen photographer or eager illustrator to take part as the Ubuntu GNOME design team are only looking to include original work.

The full submission guidelines are straightforward. In summary they seek to ensure that entries:

- Don’t include brand names, logos or trademarks
- Don’t use violent, religious or explicit imagery
- Are simple in composition with a single point of focus
- Are designed with the GNOME Shell UI in mind

It should go without saying: only submit work to which you own the full copyright, and try to aim for a minimum size of 2560 x 1600 (pixels).

For more info, see [Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 Wallpaper Contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-gnome-14-04-wallpaper-contest), and [Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) Wallpaper Contest](http://www.flickr.com/groups/2484760@N20/discuss/72157640261150753/)

Also see [Ubuntu 14.04 Wallpaper Contest](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-14-04-wallpaper-contest-changes), and [The Ubuntu 14.04 Wallpaper Contest is On](http://www.ubuntuphotographer.com/2014/01/ubuntu-14-04-wallpaper-contest/)

<sup>Sources:[Flicker](http://www.flickr.com/groups/2484760@N20/discuss/72157640261150753/) & [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-gnome-14-04-wallpaper-contest)</sup>

Comment: well I _do_ know that the ubuntu gnome's contest has started, I was asking about the contest of ubuntu itself. thanks anyways :D